# Как удалить cython speeds up из pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

Перестал работать отладчик в pycharm после того, как установил cython speeds up, при попытке отладить многопоточную программу, отладчик перестает работать после старта многопоточности,выводит это "Connected to pydev debugger (build 202.8194.15)" и дальше не идет, подскажите как удалить cython speeds up[image: cython speeds up]

Comment: Переустановка не помогла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Они лежат в `~/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharm2020.2/cythonExtensions` (для 2020.2.* версии).

P.S. Попробуй [2020.3 RC](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/), там есть фиксы отладчика при работе с многопоточностью.